# After saving object in django admin how to display it in foreign key inlining dropdown

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.10

When we save foreign key object from django admin. As following screenshot

[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlwSp.png)

Newly created object will get saved but not been able to display at same time in dropdown list.

We have *measurement* model which has *material* and *product* foreign key as showed in following snippet.

***So I want when object is created it should display the newly created option in foreign key dropdown. Please suggest how do I do that.***

Here is my code snippet

**models.py**

```
class MaterialName(models.Model):
    material_name =  models.CharField(max_length=150, default=None, null=True, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Measurement(models.Model):    
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,default=None, null=True, related_name='Measurement')
    material_name = models.ForeignKey(MaterialName,default=None, blank=Blank, related_name='materialname')
```

**admin.py**

```
class MaterialTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MaterialType
    list_display = ('material_type',)

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    inlines = [MaterialTypeAdminInline,]
```